# Mechanism of sodium hypochlorite and hydrochloric acid

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

The overall reaction for the reaction between NaClO and HCl is: $\ce{NaClO + 2HCl -> NaCl + Cl2 + H2O}$

---

To try and understand how this reaction occurs, I've thought of a simple mechanism for it. However, I don't even understand my own mechanism. Here's what I proposed:

- $\ce{NaClO + HCl -> NaCl + HClO}$
- $\ce{HClO + HCl -> Cl2 + H2O}$

The mechanism looks like it could work, but whether it would work is another question.

One problem I have with understanding it is the second step: how exactly would that work? My first thoughts were that since HCl is the stronger acid out of the two, H<sub>2</sub>ClO<sup>+</sup> and Cl<sup>-</sup> would be produced in the second step, and a third step would have something happen between both of these products to finally produce H<sub>2</sub>O and Cl<sub>2</sub>. However, I scrapped that thought since surely an ionic compound would then be produced and nothing would happen afterwards.

Now, I'm lost on what would really happen in the second step.

---

Maybe I've got it all wrong, but does anyone have any other thoughts on this? Or are there any actual proposed mechanisms for this out there?

Comment: For step 2, write HClO as HOCl. HOCl is a weak acid (pKa=7.5) that can be protonated on oxygen by HCl to give H2OCl+ (+ charge on oxygen) and Cl-. Have Cl- displace H2O from H2OCl+ to afford Cl2 (think SN2 rxn.)

Comment: @user55119 That's what I was thinking. After you said SN2 reactions, my thoughts are that a lone pair on the oxygen atom accepts a proton from HCl. The Cl- ion then attacks the chlorine atom in H2ClO+, hence Cl2 and H2O are formed.